# How to Combine Two Apps into One App (Combine two Projects)

Tags: ios, xcode

I have two Projects(**Two apps**)named **A,B** which was created seperately,Now i want to make this into **one app**,Is it Possible?

**Example** In this app it should launch with **A**(viewcontroller in Project **A**) as view and do some actions then by button tap or something like that i have go to **B**(viewcontroller in Project **B**)as View and do actions then i have to back to some view of **A**.want to go different views in both the projects then i want to relate and pass data between two project class files.

**NOTE: Both the projects have 5 storyboards** & **100 class files each.** **Both are not a libraries**.

I have gone through with workspace concept but can't get a clear idea.

Comment: pay attention not to violate apple's app store guidelines if you plan to push your app to the store.

Comment: How this will violate ?can you explain as i am new to IOS.

Comment: It is possible only one way, but in your case you need both ways, in this case you need to put all files in one project, not two.

Comment: @iphonic can you idea about working in Workspace,i had a look around everywhere but cant get anywhere,but i have idea about working with static library

Comment: you can't do. do the a single project with these features, and manage common classes etc..

Comment: [**10.4** Apps that create alternate desktop/home screen environments or simulate multi-App widget experiences will be rejected](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#user-interface)

Answer (score 2):

You could use an **Xcode workspace**.

> A workspace is an Xcode document that *groups projects and other documents* so you can work on them together. A workspace can contain any number of Xcode projects, plus any other files you want to include. In addition to *organizing all the files* in each Xcode project, a workspace *provides implicit and explicit relationships among the included projects and their targets*.

In the workspace, **they share a build directory**. To create one, go to **File > New > Workspace**, and select its location in your file system. Then, *to add an existing project* to a workspace:

1. In the project navigator, *control-click in the empty space below the
   list*.
2. Choose *Add Files to “”*.
3. *Navigate into the folder containing the .xcodeproj file to add*.
4. *Select the .xcodeproj file* and *click Add*.

Then `A` and `B` will be in *one big project*.

*Hope this will help*,

Comment: I have done till this, but cant idea about relating projects?

Comment: @Vinoth So you have 10 different storyboards?

Comment: Yes and some images too..

Comment: If I remove/change location of subproject after adding the it to main project then the subproject and associated files are shown in red color. Should not we change the location of subprojects?

Comment: Anybody are success to achive this ??

Comment: Workspace is used to maintain multiple projects in single space.It wont merge two projects and create a single target/product.